# Field "actions" gets value without assignment

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have 2 classes: **ActionsFromQuestsController, ActionsComposer**

ActionsFromQuestsController generates data of type **Action** and saves it to field **actions**

**ActionsComposer** has **actionsState, actions** fields

actionsState get new values from ActionsFromQuestsController and checks if it differs from actions field

if true, fills actions with new values
if not, get actions value to prevent overloading

`private void Update() {
    actionsState.AddRange(actionsFromQuestsController.Actions);

    if (actionsState.Except(actions).Any()) {
      Debug.Log("Composing actions");
      ComposeActions();
    } else {
      actionsState = actions;
    }
      
    Debug.Log(actionsState.Count);
    Debug.Log(actions.Count);
  }

  private void ComposeActions() {
    actions.AddRange(actionsFromQuestsController.Actions);
      
    WriteActionsToConfig(actions);
  }`

But somehow my **actions** field gets latest actions without evaluting ComposeActions method. And there are no other assignments in code

All fields are of type **List<Action>**

Comment: Felt like question need some clarifications on the class relations and structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you haven't displayed the code for `ActionsComposer` constructor, I suspect that `actions` is being initialized with similar code like:

```
private List<Action> actions;
private ActionsFromQuestsController actionsFromQuestsController;

public ActionsComposer(ActionsFromQuestsController actionsFromQuestsController)
{
    this.actionsFromQuestsController = actionsFromQuestsController;
    this.actions = actionsFromQuestsController.Actions;
}
```

By initializing `actions` directly from `actionsFromQuestsController.Actions`, you're actually setting the reference to `actionsFromQuestsController.Actions`, which will reflect any changes to each `List` with each other.

This can be solved by initializing `actions` with a new instance of `List`, for example:

```
private List<Action> actions;
private ActionsFromQuestsController actionsFromQuestsController;

public ActionsComposer(ActionsFromQuestsController actionsFromQuestsController)
{
    this.actionsFromQuestsController = actionsFromQuestsController;
    this.actions = new List<Action>(actionsFromQuestsController.Actions);
}
```

This will get the initial values from `actionsFromQuestsController.Actions` but are no longer a reference to each other.

Comment: Yeah, initialization really worked. I suspected that the issue was connected to something like that. But wasn't sure. Thanks a lot!!!